# Ctypes, creating BigEndianStructure returns 4 bytes instead of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anybody explain me why the size of these structure is 4 instead of 3?

```
from ctypes import *

class NAL_UNIT_SHORT(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("nal_unit_f", c_uint, 1),
                ("nal_unit_ref", c_uint, 2)]

print (bytes(NAL_UNIT_SHORT(0, 3)))
print (sizeof(NAL_UNIT_SHORT(0, 3)))

>>> b'`\x00\x00\x00'
>>> 4
```

What I expect:

```
  b'\x00\x01\x01'
```

Comment: Why are you expecting the size to be 3?  Your fields take a total of 3 *bits*, the only reason that the size is greater than a single byte is the padding necessary for alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the structure is 4 **bytes** (not bits). That's perfectly reasonable as the bytes string contains 4 bytes: **`** (grave accent, which is a character so 1 byte), \x00 \x00 \x00 (each one is 1 byte) so total 4 bytes.
You are getting that because you are setting the first 3 bits like the following:
**110** which is the same as **00000110**
Since you are encoding in big-endian, trying to extract hex format from that using `bytes` builtin, you will get **01100000**, which, in decimal is **96**, which is the ascii code of the grave accent.
Now the other important part is that you are using `c_uint` from ctypes, which makes your structure encoded on **4 bytes**. That's why your final bytes will look like (in binary):
**0110 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000**
in hex, that's:
**\x60 \x00 \x00 \x00**
**\x60** being a grave accent, so that explains the output:

```
b'`\x00\x00\x00'
```

Now if you want your structure to be encoded in 3 bits, use `c_uint8` instead. that way you will get:

```
b'`'
```

Which might be what you are looking for.
However, I'm assuming you are expecting `nal_unit_f` to be encoded on 1 **byte** (rather than 1 **bit**), and `nal_unit_ref` on 2 **bytes**. If that's the case, you should multiply your sizes by 8, and use the appropriate c types. Something like this:

```python
from ctypes import *

class NAL_UNIT_SHORT(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("nal_unit_f", c_uint8, 8),
                ("nal_unit_ref", c_uint16, 16)]

print (bytes(NAL_UNIT_SHORT(0, 3)))
print (sizeof(NAL_UNIT_SHORT(0, 3)))
```

However, I have no idea how did you come up with that expected output.

Comment: If you're using a full `c_uint8` and `c_uint16`, you should just drop the `8` and `16` in the third element of each `tuple`; you only provide that to define bit fields, so providing it is like a C struct defining `uint8_t nal_unit_f : 8;`; the `: 8` changes nothing and it's kinda odd to specify it. If you're using the whole type, you just omit the third value.

Comment: I know, I just kept it for clarity, and to point out that even changing from c_uint to c_uint8, you can still specify the size in bits.